# Difference Visual and GDBonline answer?

Tags: c++, class, token, move-constructor

I have a problem, when i start a program in visual studio that i got this like an answer:

```
Token()

Operator+

Token(Token&&)

~Token(): 4

Operator=

~Token(): 4
```

But when i compiled , same source code in GDBonline i got this like an answer:

```
Token()

Operator+

Operator=

~Token(): 4
```

**I want to ask you which answer is a good one?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class Token{

    public:
        int a{1};
        Token(){ //default constructor
            cout << "Token()" << endl;
        };
        Token(int a0): a{a0} { //parametric constructor
            cout << "Token(int)" << endl;
        }
        Token(const Token& t){ //copy constructor
            this->a = t.a;
            cout << "Token(const Token&)" << endl;
        }
        Token(Token&& t) noexcept{ //move constructor
            this->a = t.a;
            cout << "Token(Token&&)" << endl;
        }
        Token& operator=(const Token& t0){ //operator =
            this->a = t0.a;
            cout << "Operator=" << endl;
            return *this;
        }
        Token operator+(const Token& t0){ //operator +
            Token t;
            t.a = this->a + t0.a;
            cout << "Operator+" << endl;
            return t;
            //return Token{this->a + t0.a};
        }
        ~Token(){ //destructor
            cout << "~Token(): " << this->a << endl;
        };
};

int main(){

    Token t0;

    Token t1{3};

    Token t2;

    t0 = t1 + t2;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Token(int)` is at least missing in both...

Comment: You might look at (n)rvo ((Named) Return value optimization) or copy elision.

Comment: What compiler setting did you use for both?

Comment: I didnt change setting in visual studio 2017 and in GNU online i used c++17

Comment: Not same output [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/oB6rB6)...

Comment: I forgot to check that I only care about part of the answer for t0 = t1 + t2